# Java file upload to windows shared folder with authentication

Tags: java, networking, samba

I'm trying to upload some files on a shared folder where I'm granted on with full control, but I see that connection is not working for some authentication reasons. This is the piece of code I've used for some writing tests:

```
    String destination = "serverX/shareFolder/";

    String domain = "myDomain";
    String smbFile = "smb://"+domain+"/user1:pwd1@"+destination;
    SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(smbFile);
    SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
    sfos.write("Test".getBytes());
    sfos.close();
```

this is the error I've received:

```
jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is looks like the code is good, the problem seems to be the account you are using. Have you tried other account? or maybe you can "unlock" the account someway at the server.